# Powershell script. Encoding in COM object Outlook.Application

Tags: powershell, email, encoding, outlook

I am trying to create a powershell script to send a series of emails using the Outlook COM object, however, if I add an accent to the "Subject" of the message, it is encoded wrong.

here is my code:

```
$obj = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $obj.CreateItem(0) 
$mail.To = "ramon.casta@gmail.com"
$mail.Subject = "Hola Ramon te envío la factura" 
$mail.GetInspector.Activate()
```

And here is a screenshot of how the issue is displayed in the application (The outlook client)

[image of the outlook subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3OyL.png)
**"Hola Ramon te envÃ­o la factura"**

I have tried to code it in multiple ways but can't find any solution that works.

Comment: Can you try it with single quotes?

Comment: A kind of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: UTF-8 byte sequence for `í` _Latin Small Letter I With Acute_ is `0xC3`, `0xAD` (_Latin Capital Letter A With Tilde_ and _Soft Hyphen_ if interpreted as `cp1252`/`latin1` characters).

Comment: yes, I have tried with single quotes but it still doesen't work

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, single- vs. double-quoting cannot be expected to make a difference here. This is an _encoding_ problem, as JosefZ points out. The UTF16-LE .NET string is translated to UTF-8, but Outlook interprets it as ANSI-encoded. I don't see the problem in Outlook 2019, but perhaps older versions are affected and/or there is a setting that controls this behavior.

Comment: @mklement0, where can i find related topics to this? Just so I can get familiar with what the heck you guys are talkin about lol

Comment: Isn't this just a question of going into the settings of your Outlook and selecting UTF-8 in the `Preferred encoding for outgoing messages` ? See [here](https://support.streetcontxt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015329011-Setting-Default-Encoding-In-Outlook)